# Install Angular with Ionic already installed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, installation

I've installed Ionic and as it uses Angular I presume that when I installed ionic I also installed angular, right?

So if I installed angular like the site suggests: `npm install angular@1.6.4` I would be installing angular twice?

I ran this command `npm list -g --depth=0` and the result is:

> /usr/local/lib 
>   ├── cordova@6.5.0 
>   ├── ionic@2.2.2 
>   └── npm@4.4.4

Angular should be listed, shouldn't?

I checked the folder `~/.npm` and the only thing similar to angular is a directory called `@angular`.

So, in order to be able to build a website using angular, should I just install it with the above command? Is there a chance that is conflicts with angular from ionic's installation?

Obs: I'm using macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This goes along with dependencies and you'll find everywhere throughout NPM, NuGet etc.  If you install Ionic, for example and Ionic uses Angular it has a config or configuration file that links to the Ionics dependencies.  Ionic depends on Angular to run, so in it's config file (package.config) or package.json will show what version of Angular it uses.  It is included in the Ionic files, but not for use for your project.
You'll want to download Angular for your project as well.  You'll also want to pay attention to versioning as well.  I assume if you aren't familiar with the config files you'll also want to look into this as well.

Comment: By versioning I mean the version of Angular or the package you include.